# Use VirtualizingStackPanel with multiple ListBox inside ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollviewer, virtualizingstackpanel

I have multiple `ListBoxes` below each other inside a `ScrollViewer`. These listboxes contain a different number of items (the actual number is not known before loading). These listboxes need to be shown like this for UI flow and to get a single scrollbar. However, the `ScrollViewer` disables the working of the `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

Because sometimes a few of these listboxes can get thousands of items in them, this doesn't really perform that well. I was wondering if there's any way to still use the `VirtualizingStackPanel` for non-visible items within the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Why don't you show all items in a single ListBox? You may have different DataTemplates for different item types.

Comment: I've thought about that but the items are all grouped by a header that is different per listbox. I've been reviewing ListView (which can do grouping) but that's not really the same with its group headers and is also limited in terms of how to control the data order.

Comment: I'm just walking-by person. Are you really sure that people want to scroll among veryvery long thousands items? Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks and sadly, yes, some people do want that, although personally I don't think it's very useful :)

Comment: The `ListBox` can also do grouping, and you can control how to sort its items.